# Use u1sdtool to show published files

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

Can I somehow use `u1sdtool` to find out which files have I published on Ubuntu One (and possibly with their public URL)? Now, I have to use the web interface for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use u1sdtool for this, but you can use `SyncDaemonTool`, which lets you talk to Ubuntu One's *syncdaemon* directly, to do what you want via a short Python script:

```
from twisted.internet import glib2reactor
glib2reactor.install()
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from ubuntuone.platform.tools import SyncDaemonTool

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def print_public_files():
    print "calling"
    sd = SyncDaemonTool()
    pf = yield sd.get_public_files()
    for f in pf:
        print "%(path)s -> %(public_url)s" % f
    reactor.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reactor.callWhenRunning(print_public_files)
    reactor.run()
```

You'll find documentation on everything that `SyncDaemonTool` can do on the [Ubuntu One developer site](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/syncdaemontool).